# v-if Not work when the function return true or false [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, vuejs2, azure-storage

I am working on **VueJs**, And In my `template` section .. I defined a condition to check if the image URL exists or not.

`template`:

```
<div v-for="(sub, key) in Work.sub" :key="sub.id" >
  <span v-if="Image('https://XXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXX/XXXXX-' + key +'.png')" > 
     <b-img :src="'https://XXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXX/XXXXX-' + key +'.png'" />
  </span>
  <span v-else>
     <b-img :src="default_avatar"/> 
  </span>
</div>
```

In `script`:

```
Image: function(img_url)
{
   return axios({
      method: "GET",
      timeout: 3000,
      headers: {
        .......................
      },
      url: img_url
   })
   .then( function(response){
      this.ifImageExist = true;
      return this.ifImageExist;
   })
   .catch( function(error){
      this.ifImageExist = false;
      return this.ifImageExist;
   })
},
```

For `default_avatar` it is aleady definded in the `data section` and no problem with it.

My problem is when the `Image` function checks if the image URL exists or not. If it exists it provides the image in the given URL, but if it does not exist, the image will be blank!

**For example:**

when I run the code, I result will be like this:

[image]

But I want the first image to filled by default image, not show does not exist icon!

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the code of b-img component ?
Also I think v-if expression will always be true as your Image function returns a promise and not the actual true/false you are returning. So, even if the image doesn't exist you v-if div will render.

Comment: b-img is component predefined by bootstrap VueJs: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/image/, How can I solve the problem with promise? @fullmetal

Comment: It's tag not component, sorry! @fullmetal

Comment: Yes, you can.. you can make a data property namely ifImageExist and set it to true or false in then/catch respectively. And then in template you can use 
v-if="ifImageExists".

Comment: I try to define a new variable call it ifImageEcist and set its value false at the beginning, then inside the axios, when it goes to then I change the value of it true when it in catch the value will be false .. and then return the value of it .. check the update of the question, but it does not work for me .. still the same problem. @fullmetal

Comment: @fullmetal if you can explain it for me in separate answer it will be good for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative solution:** It looks like the only diff between the `v-if` and `v-else` is `b-img`'s `src`, so an alternative would be to move the logic into JavaScript, mapping `Work.sub` into an array of image URLs that default to `default_avatar` only if the URL doesn't resolve.

So your template would be:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(img, index) in images" :key="index">
    <b-img :src="img" />
  </div>
</template
```

You'd add a data property to hold the image URLs:

```
data() {
  return {
    images: []
  }
}
```

And a watcher on `Work.sub`, which sets `this.images`:

```
watch: {
  'Work.sub': {
    immediate: true,
    async handler(sub) {
      // For each image URL, attempt to fetch the image, and if it returns
      // data (image exists), collect the URL. Otherwise, default.
      this.images = await Promise.all(Object.keys(sub).map(async (key) => {
        const img = sub[key];
        if (!img) return this.default_avatar;

        const url = `//placekitten.com/${img}`;
        const { data } = await axios.get(url);
        return data ? url : this.default_avatar;
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/w0owqmvkzw)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your function `Image()` doesn't return a `Boolean` it returns a `Promise` (from axios), 
so `v-if` evaluates as **true**;

To get `v-if` working with a API call (Axios GET), the simplest way is to turn that Image method in a **Async Method**

```
Image: async function(img_url)
{
   return axios({
      method: "GET",
      timeout: 3000,
      headers: {
        .......................
      },
      url: img_url
   })
   .then( function(response){
      this.ifImageExist = true;
      return this.ifImageExist;
   })
   .catch( function(error){
      this.ifImageExist = false;
      return this.ifImageExist;
   })
},
```

If you have all build configured right to work with `async function`, the method will wait for the response and evaluate to the `Boolean` which `v-if` is expecting.